# Javascript sleep() function executed early

Tags: javascript

I am trying to figure out why in my Code section, this.sleep(5000) seems to be getting called before my draw function, because it doesn't get drawn to the canvas until after sleep is done. any insights on why this isn't working the way I want it to?

Sleep function:

```
sleep: function(milliseconds) {
    setTimeout(function(){
        var start = new Date().getTime();
        while ((new Date().getTime() - start) < milliseconds){
        // Do nothing
        }
    },0);
},
```

Code:

```
var g = new Graph(this.diagram);
g.DrawPolygons(ctx,"blue");

this.sleep(5000);
```

Comment: Your sleep function will "lock up" the browser until that while loop is done.  By "lock up", I mean no other JavaScript or even UI updates will run until it's done.  I ***highly*** suggest against this method and suggest you think of a better way.

Comment: What is a better way? I guess I could use setInterval

Comment: You better search for callbacks in the draw method documentation, if it's a 3rd party, or adding one if it's your own method. As @RocketHazmat already commented, sleep in JavaScript won't always work as you would expect. Also, trusting that your graph will render in 5 seconds is not a good practice... may cause you bugs.

Comment: If you don't want to nest 5 levels for 5 sleeps, you can consider promises, they give you syntax that looks like `.sleep` but doesn't nest or look fugly :)

Comment: @BenjaminGruenbaum: Or you can use a loop or recursion or something! ;-)  Yeah, promises are probably a good idea here.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### Short answer

Don't do it this way. *Even* if you get it to work, it will be inconsistent, will cause you many problems, and is almost globally considered bad practice.

### Long answer

JavaScript runtimes are almost always designed to [be asynchronous](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/async/deferred/). Your `while` loop is intended to make everything... wait. You cannot (or at least shouldn't) do that in most JavaScript environments.

Instead, **schedule** events/functions to be executed some number of `ms` in the future. This is what [`setTimeout`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window.setTimeout) is for. This removes the need for a `sleep` function.

Here's what your code might look like after the changes described above are applied:

```
var g = new Graph(this.diagram);
g.DrawPolygons(ctx, "blue");

setTimeout(function() {
    g.DrawPolygons(ctx, "red"); // Or whatever

    setTimeout(function() {
       g.DrawPolygons(ctx, "yellow"); // Or whatever

       // etc..
    }, 5000);
}, 5000);
```

### ES2015 update - using promises

To avoid potential deeply nested `setTimeout`s, you can use this

```
const sleep ms = new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve,ms));
```

which is simply a promise that resolves in `ms` milliseconds. This allows you to keep everything in one block:

```
var g = new Graph(this.diagram);
g.DrawPolygons(ctx, "blue");

(async () => {
  g.DrawPolygons(ctx, "red");
  await sleep(5000);
  g.DrawPolygons(ctx, "yellow");
  await sleep(5000);
  // ...
})()
```

Note two things:

- Under the hood, there are still events/callback. It *looks* like C's or Python's sleep but behave *very differently*.
- You can only use this inside asynchronous functions. See [here](https://javascript.info/async-await) for more information.

Comment: Remember, `this` inside the `setTimeout` won't be what you expect :)

Comment: @RocketHazmat You're absolutely correct; I apologize for missing that. Edited to make use of lexical scoping.

Comment: s/JavaScript/The DOM API - JavaScript the language itself has no notion of concurrency, it's all the host environment. setTimeout is part of the DOM API :)

Comment: @BenjaminGruenbaum I have personally been an advocate of being accurate with terminology regarding *what is what* with the DOM, scripting, HTML/CSS, etc. It ended up causing unnecessary confusion in some cases and had very little addition to the actual discussion at hand. In this case, JavaScript (as a language by itself) has very few ways of interfacing with tangible media. As such, I felt it was unnecessary to try and nit-pick on the terminology when the point is made clear. Browser runtimes and Node.js, for instance, have a complete adoption of asynchronous/concurrent management.

Comment: @BenjaminGruenbaum But anyhow, I do utterly agree with you and appreciate your comment.

Comment: You don't have to nitpick, I just appreciate being precise here. A lot of people using incorrect terminology (a common example is JSON objects for JS object literals). You can just as easily say "JavaScript APIs are almost always meant..." instead of "JavaScritp is ...". People not knowing what the DOM API is and what the language is get very confused when they go to NodeJS and find out timers work differently for example. Other than that your answer is spot on.

Comment: @BenjaminGruenbaum Great suggestion. I have thusly edited my answer. Thanks!

Comment: I don't understand how the 2nd `this.sleep()` works.  Isn't there a problem with `this` when the callback is called from `setTimeout()`?  Don't you have to use `.bind()`.

Comment: @jfriend00 I believe the callback for `setTimeout` has `this == window` since `setTimeout` is really `window.setTimeout`. I may be wrong.

Comment: So, `sleep()` is a global function?  If so, why alias `setTimeout()` with a new function name that has the arguments reversed?  You might as well just use `setTimeout()` and make the code more readable to people who know regular javascript.  Plus, this probably won't work in strict mode because `this` may be undefined.

Comment: @jfriend00 `sleep` is indeed a global function in the code above. The goal of this answer isn't to rewrite the OP's application from the ground up to make it "best," it is to answer his/her question. He/she can practice best judgment with all the aspects of the application that the question doesn't directly concern.

Comment: @jfriend00 I also get the impression you're trying to find ways that something might NOT work. With all due respect, that isn't very helpful.

Comment: @Chris - Look, I upvoted you, but I don't think your recommended code is as good as it could be so I commented.  The best answers often incorporate feedback from commenters.

Answer (score 4):

There are several problems with the code you've posted.  First off, you should never use a `while` loop to halt code execution.

Secondly, you're setting a timeout, which allows other code to be executed in the interim (yes, even if the timeout is zero seconds).  Remove that and you should be able to pause execution (BUT DON'T DO THIS):

```
sleep: function(milliseconds) {
    var start = new Date().getTime();
    while ((new Date().getTime() - start) < milliseconds){
      // Do nothing
    }
},
```

However, occupying the JS thread means that other browser operations (redraws, etc) will be halted until your sleep function exits.  Just having this code in your JS file is an antipattern, you'd be better off finding a different way to solve your problem.  Read up on [the XY problem](http://goo.gl/taIqf) and ask a new question.

In case all you wanted to do was execute some code after a certain interval *without* blocking everything else, `setTimeout` is all you need.

```
sleep: function(ms, funcToExecute) {
  setTimeout(funcToExecute, ms);
},
```

(Though at this point, `sleep` is redundant)

Comment: That is what I want. To pause a few seconds before each redraw

Comment: That's not going to allow the draw method to do its job. See comment by @RocketHazmat

Comment: @gustavohenke I answered his question, and then explained why it was a bad idea.

Comment: This does not deserve 3 downvotes. Not only did he answer the question, he explained why it shouldn't be used and gave a correct method of doing it. +1

Comment: @RUJordan The downvotes were, I believe, made before he/she showed a correct method of doing it. Agreed, though.

Comment: @Chris (I'm a he) I had a one-sentence warning in my original answer, but that wasn't good enough for the downvoters, I guess.  I did expand it in later versions.

Comment: Why are you recommending a `while` loop for some number of milliseconds in your first code block.  This is just basically NEVER the right way to write Javascript.  It locks up the browser during that duration and if the time is long enough will even trigger a warning in the browser about unstable script.  The code needs to be rewritten to be asynchronous.

Comment: @jfriend00 Nice trigger-happy attitude.  Did you read the rest of my answer (or heck, the comments above you) before downvoting?

Comment: @SomeKittensUx2666 - yeah I read it and your answer starts with a bad recommendation.  Remove that bad recommendation and I'll remove my downvote.  I have a right to disagree with what you've said.  That first code should simply not be there at all in any cases.

Comment: @jfriend00 are you kidding me? He explicitly says it's bad to do that... "you'd be better off finding a different way to solve your problem"

Comment: @jfriend00 you have no basis here. But by all means leave the downvote that's your choice. Doesn't make him any less right and all you're interested in is making him wrong ;)

Comment: I still don't understand why you tell him how to fix the problem in the while loop at all since it's simply not relevant to the solution at all because the solution involves getting rid of the while loop.  I did remove my downvote with the latest edits.

Comment: @jfriend00 I'm correcting a misconception about `setTimeout` while still telling him that there's a better way.  Two birds, one stone.

Comment: @SomeKittensUx2666 - you're correcting his code in an anti-pattern.  I don't see the point at all.  Telling him you absolutely cannot use the while loop and not repeating the bad code and then showing him correctly implemented code he can use would be better.

Comment: but you **can** use a while loop, it just isn't recommended. I think Kittens is spot on here. The OP had a mindset and Kittens corrected his code so he can now learn something about what he was doing wrong. He then outlined why it was bad and what should be done instead. +1 from me.

Comment: @jfriend00: SomeKittens isn't correcting the OP's code with bad code, but rather he's explaining why it isn't working as expected (because of sync vs async). SomeKittens then shows why this is a bad idea, and how the problem can be solved in a better way. Surely that makes this the best answer.

Answer (score 2):

This is happening because of how JavaScript's `setTimeout` works.  When you do:

```
setTimeout(function(){}, 0)
```

You are *not* actually telling it to run the function after 0ms (the lowest value is actually 4ms, but that's besides the point).  You are telling it to run the function in the future.  What it actually does is put the function at "the end of the stack".  It'll finish running the function that called it, and maybe even run some UI redraws before it runs the timeout.

If this code is ran in a loop, your timeouts will *not* run at all when you think they will ;)

Also, remember JavaScript is *single threaded*.  One thread runs your code as well as the UI redraws.  Doing a `while` loop that does nothing and waits for 5 seconds ***will*** lock up the browser.  It will prevent *any* user interaction and UI redraws.  It might even make the OS think the browser crashed.  DO NOT DO THIS!

Instead, try setting a timeout to run the next polygon after 5000ms:

```
var g = new Graph(this.diagram);
g.DrawPolygons(ctx,"blue");

setTimeout(function(){
    // Code to run after the "sleep"

    // Maybe another shape
    g.DrawPolygons(ctx, "red");
}, 5000);
```

Comment: To be fair, the lowest value is 4ms after 5 timeouts if I recall correctly. 0 ms is perfectly doable in a modern browser with setTimeout - at least according to the spec. I may be wrong here.

Comment: Also, not the same thread runs your code as well as UI redraws, UI redraws can be on different threads depending on the browser - UI redraws just wait for the JS thread to yield. The overall notion of the answer is correct though :)

Comment: @BenjaminGruenbaum: I got the info about the 4ms from: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window.setTimeout#Minimum.2F_maximum_delay_and_timeout_nesting (unless I mis-interpreted the docs).  As for the UI redraws, I remember that I made the browser lock up from doing `async:false` (in a jQuery AJAX) and also from a "sleep" loop like this.  Maybe browsers nowadays won't lock up, but they used to and it's still bad practice to use those methods.

Comment: Interesting. From what I understand the 4ms clamp only applies after the fourth timeout (that is, there were more than 4 timeouts in the timeout queue. At least - [that's what the specification says](http://www.whatwg.org/specs/web-apps/current-work/multipage/timers.html) - "Timers can be nested; after five such nested timers, however, the interval is forced to be at least four milliseconds.". As for threads, all I said is that it's not on the same thread. When the JavaScript thread doesn't notify the UI drawing thread it's done it is "locking" it :)

Comment: @BenjaminGruenbaum: Maybe I did misunderstand the 4ms thing :-)